# The skipIf is not skipping the test method that already met the condition

Tags: python, unit-testing, pycharm

Here is my Code, I'm not sure if I lack or miss some code but it is not skipping the test2.

```
import unittest

class AppTesting (unittest.TestCase):
 skipYes = ""

def test_1(self):
    print("Test 1: " + str(AppTesting.skipYes))
    AppTesting.skipYes = "Yes"
    print("Test 1: " + str(AppTesting.skipYes))

@unittest.skipIf(str(skipYes) == "Yes", "Skip condition")
def test_2(self):
    print("Test 2 skipYes is: " + str(AppTesting.skipYes))
    print("This is Test 2")

def test_3(self):
    print("This is Test 3")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your decorator is evaluated when the module is loaded on the test run together with the test class definition, hence the `skipYes` variable at that point will always be an empty string `""`, as defined in the class.

Changing this variable inside the test methods won't make any difference, as the test runner has already collected what tests to run and what to skip.

As a solution, from Python 3.4 you can use subtests:

```py
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_some(self):
        skipTest = False

        with self.subTest('subtest1'):
            self.assertTrue(False)

        ...

        if not skipTest:
            with self.subTest('subtest2'):
                self.assertFalse(True)
```

**DOCS:** https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#distinguishing-test-iterations-using-subtests

Comment: I see, I am planning to skip test_2, depending on the result of test_1, and I'm not sure how will I get the value on test_1, this is the reason I created a variable skipYes... I'm having hard time researching for this. would you mind to help me bro?

Will be there a way to change the value of the variable?